# Zend_File_Transfer_Http How to set uploaded file name

Tags: zend-framework, upload

how to set a new random name for the uploaded file directly using Zend_File_Transfer_Http?

Comment: Have a look at Rename filter at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.filters.html .

Answer (score 2):

You should try to use a Filter
for example:

```
$adapter= new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$adapter->addFilter('Rename',array('target' => $SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/uploadedfiles/whatevername.jpg'));
$adapter->receive();
```